# Compare two list of objects in where clause of LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to compare two list of objects on the basis of their properties using `LINQ`. I have created a list of objects and another list is stored in database.
The classes are as following:

```
class A
{
    int a1;
    int a2;
} 
class B
{
    int b1;
    int b2;
}
```

I am comparing `List<A> a` to `List<B> b` using conditions `(a1==b1 and a2==b2)`or `(a1==b2 and a2==b1)`. if any condition gets true it returns a third `List<C>` with properties of `class A`.
Here is the following LINQ I am using:

```
(from a in context.A
                 where b.Any(m => (m.b1 == a.a1 && m.b2 == a.a2) || (m.b1 == a.a2 && m.b2 == a.a1))
                 select new C
                 {
                     c1 = a.a1,
                     c2 = a.a2,
                 }).ToList();
```

But its throwing an error as:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator

please help me to figure out right Linq query.

Comment: Have you tried doing as suggested? Use the Contains operation?

Comment: i have tried `Contains` operation but not able to figure out how can I use it for mentioned condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(
    from a in context.A.ToArray()
    where b.Any(m => (m.b1 == a.a1 && m.b2 == a.a2) || (m.b1 == a.a2 && m.b2 == a.a1))
    select new C
    {
        c1 = a.a1,
        c2 = a.a2,
    }
).ToList();
```

This brings `A` local which then allows you to use `b` which is also local.

Of course, this only works if `A` is small enough to be fully loaded in memory first.

Comment: it works. Thanks. But what if `List<A>` contains large amount of objects?

Comment: @Vivek - If `List<A>` is under 2GB in size it may well fit into memory in a 32-bit exe, but if larger then you need to go to a 64-bit exe, but, from memory, there is a 2GB for a single object instance so that would be your hard limit.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's not only whether it can fit in memory but also a performance issue. Filtering server side is going to be a lot faster for large As

Comment: @RuneFS - I couldn't think of a way to do this server-side. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
context.A.Where(a=>b.Any(m => (m.b1 == a.a1 && m.b2 == a.a2) || (m.b1 == a.a2 && m.b2 == a.a1))).select(a=> new C{ c1 = a.a1,
                     c2 = a.a2});
```

Comment: B is not a part of `DBContext` . It is created by me.